# How can I emulate the perspective used by android view's `setRotationY` etc on another platform?

Tags: android, skia

I would like to emulate the behaviour of transformed Android views in a different context (CSS 3d transforms, iOS CALayers, and OpenGL), so that given particular viewport dimensions and the same rotations/translations/scaling, elements will be projected into the same screen-space coordinates across all platforms.

The android documentation doesn't shed much light on the fov (or the exact projection matrix) used.  Naturally I can invest some time fiddling around and get a good-enough approximation, but does anyone know offhand what this may be, assuming it is fixed across all devices, or if it in fact differs from device to device?

## Update

I've been digging deeper into the source for `android.graphics.Camera`, which implements the underlying logic for this behaviour using a thin layer over a Skia 3D View (`Sk3DView`), so now my question applies over here, too.  That is- how can I build a 4x4 projection matrix to emulate a Sk3DView?